# How use chart control in .net 3.5 visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-3.5, microsoft-chart-controls

I am working on visual studio 2012 .NET 3.5 web application and am trying to use the Chart Control.

I have installed mschart.exe and tried to drag and drop the DLL into the toolbox and also tried adding reference to the project.

But, when I import the control, I get the following message:

> The following controls were successfully added to the toolbox but are not enabled in the active designer:
>
> Chart
>
> Make sure the controls to add are compatible with the current designer and .NET framework version

How can I get the control to appear in my toolbox?

Comment: I have solved it by copy and pasting the DLL into the bin folder of my project and then have dragged it into the toolbox. Now i can see the chart control in toolbox.